# Email Validation Ionic2

Tags: regex, validation, angular, ionic2

I am building an app with Ionic2. In the app I have a form that uses formBuilder to validate each input field. I figure for the email input field I would just use Validators.pattern with a regex string. But after trying multiple different regex expression, I can't get it to work. The form says that the field is invalid even when I enter a valid email address such as 'thisisanemail@gmail.com'. The issue is not with the regex expression but with my implementation of the Validator.

Here is my formBuilder:

```
 this.inputGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    fullName : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])],
    email : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/')])],
    subject : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(30), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])],
    message : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(500), Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z ]*'), Validators.required])],
     });
```

Why would the Validator claim that is an email, such as the example above, is invalid? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The only thing your regex should do in the email field is to check if there is an `@` somewhere. Then your app needs to actually try and send an email to it (and have the user click a link to ascertain that it arrived at the correct location). I haven't looked at your regex more closely, but I'm sure it'll have many false positives and false negatives. The same thing goes for the other regexes - why would you only allow names consisting of nothing but ASCII letters and spaces? You're already excluding half the Irish/Scottish population with that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend [Validator interface](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/Validator-interface.html) and create email validator directive as below so that you can use same directive in another form also :

```
import { Directive, forwardRef, Attribute } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, AbstractControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[email-validator][formControlName],[email-validator][ngModel]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: EmailValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})

class EmailValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  validate(c: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    let regExp = /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/;

    if (!regExp.test(c.value)) {
      return {"invalidEmail": true};
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this **without directive**

Validation:

```
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group(this.createValitation());

      private createValitation() {
        return {
          email: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.pattern(GlobalValidator.EMAIL_REGEX)]]
        };
      }
```

---

Regex :

```
export class GlobalValidator {

  public static EMAIL_REGEX = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

}
```